# how to setup sonicwall tz210 to port forward packets received from external ip to another external ip

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, sonicwall, external-ip

i have a sonicwall tz210 on a fixed ip, say ip1. And then i have, let's say a legacy server, with external ip ip2, which sends data to ip1 (and I have another server on ip1 behind the sonicwall which receives and processes that data). I would like to set up a new server on a different external ip ip3 that will receive and process data from the legacy server.

How can I setup the sonicwall so that the packets received from the legacy server (from an external ip) are port forwarded to the external ip address ip3?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Translated NAT policy to point to the new server. Assuming this is what your NAT policy currently looks like here's what you would want to change:

Old:

```
Source Original     Translated     Destination Original     Translated          Service
ip2                 Original       ip1                      old_internal_ip1    ip2_service_group
```

New:

```
Source Original     Translated     Destination Original     Translated          Service
ip2                 Original       ip1                      new_internal_ip3    ip2_service_group
```

Comment: packets from ip2 is port forwarded to a local ip behind ip1, the legacy server can't be changed from sending data to ip1

Comment: See my edits, your question is still pretty hard to follow. But I think that's what you need.